# docker-compose up -d --build "$@" building images with wrong names

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker-compose up -d --build "$@" building images with wrong names

I would like to build the Docker images with the following names:

```
denpal_cli:latest
denpal_php:latest
denpal_nginx:latest
```

Unfortunately docker images produces this result:

```
workspace_php:latest
workspace_nginx:latest
denpal:latest
```

This way I cannot push them to the Docker pub with their proper names, or I have to do a hackey:

```
docker tag denpal:latest denpal_cli:latest
docker tag workspace_php:latest denpal_php:latest
docker tag workspace_nginx:latest denpal_nginx:latest
```

Docker ps shows this as the result:

```
workspace_cli_1       /sbin/tini -- /lagoon/entr ...   Up      9000/tcp
workspace_mariadb_1   /sbin/tini -- /lagoon/entr ...   Up      0.0.0.0:32768->3306/tcp
workspace_nginx_1     /sbin/tini -- /lagoon/entr ...   Up      8080/tcp
workspace_php_1       /sbin/tini -- /lagoon/entr ...   Up      9000/tcp
workspace_redis_1     /sbin/tini -- /lagoon/entr ...   Up      6379/tcp
workspace_solr_1      /sbin/tini -- /lagoon/entr ...   Up      0.0.0.0:32769->8983/tcp
workspace_varnish_1   /sbin/tini -- /lagoon/entr ...   Up      8080/tcp
```

This is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '2.3'

x-test-project:
  # Project name (leave `&test-project` when you edit this)
  &test-project denpal

x-volumes:
  &default-volumes
    # Define all volumes you would like to have real-time mounted into the docker containers
    volumes:
      - .:/app:delegated

x-environment:
  &default-environment
    TEST_PROJECT: *test-project

x-user:
  &default-user
    # The default user under which the containers should run. Change this if you are on linux and run with another user than id `1000`
    user: '1000'

services:

  cli: # cli container, will be used for executing composer and any local commands (drush, drupal, etc.)
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.cli
    image: *test-project # this image will be reused as `CLI_IMAGE` in subsequent Docker builds
    << : *default-volumes # loads the defined volumes from the top
    user: root
    environment:
      << : *default-environment # loads the defined environment variables from the top

  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
      args:
        CLI_IMAGE: *test-project # Inject the name of the cli image
    << : *default-volumes # loads the defined volumes from the top
    << : *default-user # uses the defined user from top
    depends_on:
      - cli # basically just tells docker-compose to build the cli first
    networks:
      - test-network
      - default

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.php
      args:
        CLI_IMAGE: *test-project
    << : *default-volumes # loads the defined volumes from the top
    << : *default-user # uses the defined user from top
    depends_on:
      - cli # basically just tells docker-compose to build the cli first
    environment:
      << : *default-environment # loads the defined environment variables from the top


  mariadb:
    image: mariadb-drupal
    ports:
      - "3306" # exposes the port 3306 with a random local port, find it with `docker-compose port mariadb 3306`
    << : *default-user # uses the defined user from top
    environment:
      << : *default-environment

  redis:
    image: redis
    << : *default-user # uses the defined user from top
    environment:
      << : *default-environment

  solr:
    image: solr:6.6-drupal
    << : *default-user # uses the defined user from top
    ports:
      - "8983" # exposes the port 8983 with a random local port, find it with `docker-compose port solr 8983`
    environment:
      << : *default-environment


  varnish:
    image: varnish-drupal
    links:
      - nginx # links varnish to the nginx in this docker-compose project, or it would try to connect to any nginx running in docker
    << : *default-user # uses the defined user from top
    environment:
      << : *default-environment
      VARNISH_BYPASS: "true" # by default we bypass varnish, change to 'false' or remove in order to tell varnish to cache if possible
    networks:
      - test-network
      - default

networks:
  test-network:
    external: true
```

Workspace is the name of the Jenkins directory where the build is happening from.

I would also like the containers to come online with names as denpal_cli_1, denpal_mariadb_1, etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: did you try to use "container_name" for each service? this should force docker to use the specified name or fail if the name already exist.

Answer (score 2):

By default, compose will use the current directory name as a "project name" and will prefix all your images/services/volumes/networks/etc. with that name. You can [set a project name explicitly](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name) using the `-p` option or by setting the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable. So for your use case, you could set `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` to `denali`.

Answer (score 0):

To build images with specific prefixes you should specify it on `image`.

To name containers whatever you like, use the `container_name` configuration.

For instance, you want a container to be named like apache but the image is named httpd:

```
version: '3'

services:
  apache:
    image: apache_2.4:latest (my custom tag)
    container_name: my-apache
    build:
      context: my_dockerfile_folder/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-apache (The dockerfile which will build from httpd:2.4)
[...]
```

results:

Image: apache_2.4:latest

Container_name: my-apache